# How to draw this diagram using tikz?

Tags: tikz-cd

How to draw this diagram using tikz?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}
        X \ar[r, hook , "\hat{\beta}", swap]\ar[d,"\beta", swap] & M\ar[dl]\\
        G\\
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Off-topic with the tag of the user...but it is possible to create the same image with `xy` package for typesetting graphs and diagrams. The parameters `@R=3pc` (**R= row**) and `@C=3pc` (**C=column**) inform you that it is a matrix. Therefore you can increase o decrease the size of the matrix.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=3pc@C=3pc{
    X \ar[d]_{\beta}\ar@{^{(}->}[r]_{\hat{\beta}} & \ar[dl] M \\
    G                       &  }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I too like `xy-pic`

Comment: @MadyYuvi Also to me ...much...:-)